# Layout not showing Properly as needed

Tags: android, android-layout, layout

[image]

Please see attached screen shot, i am showing Image Popups using Google Maps Version2

I am looking for three small changes in my **popup**, and these are:

1. want to show image on complete background, like still my image covering only 50% area of marker
2. also want to cover white area of marker (white at corners)
3. and what if i want to show black shadows at corners

**popup.xml:-**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:color/background_dark"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:background="@null"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:contentDescription="@string/icon"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:maxLines="1"        
            android:textColor="@android:color/background_light"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:typeface="sans"
            android:textStyle="bold"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/snippet"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/title"
            android:typeface="sans"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:textColor="@android:color/background_light" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I think i have to use wider image as marker's background still using [this](http://misc.commonsware.com/mapsv2/UN_HQ.jpg), and i am concern about these white corners (i don't want to see it)

Answer (score 2):

Change the four "wrap_content" in your RelativeLayout and ImageView to "Match_parent".
The imageview however, might look stretched, so you should consider using a wider one.

Answer (score 2):

Replace **ImageView** with this  ( **change wrap_content to match_parent** )

```
 <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/icon"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:background="@null"
    android:contentDescription="@string/icon"/>
```

......rest xml code

Comment: using match_parent for ImageView it shows full width marker with image in center, which is totally wrong and not required

Comment: @Sonali have you tried this, what happens when you apply this.?

Answer (score 1):

```
     <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:background="@null"
        android:scaleType="fitxy"
        android:contentDescription="@string/icon"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Try this way,hope this will help you to solve your problem.**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:background="@drawable/background"> // Here set your custom pop window background with with and black shadow

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher"> // Here set your place image
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:textColor="@android:color/background_light"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:typeface="sans"
            android:text="Great Hotel - A Luxury Sun"
            android:textStyle="bold"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/snippet"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:typeface="sans"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:text="$359"
            android:textColor="@android:color/background_light" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: @Sonali,Okay so try to define id for this layout and set background image at run time.